# Apply transforms to all other keyframes

Tags: modeling, keyframes

I have the following problem: I have modeled a simple robot consisting of an armature with some bones and some CAD parts parented to the bones. During modelling, I applied several transforms to obtain the desired shapes. Now I just realized that all these transforms have only been applied to one specific keyframe somewhere in the timeline. For all other keyframes, all transforms are lost.

[image]

Is it possible to delete the timeline except that one frame or to copy the keyframe to all other keyframes?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot you have multiple object selected. 
You can select all keys in a frame when you select only the armature (Armature.001), then there will be a yellow dot in the *Dope Sheet Summary* line.

1. Right click (<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>) to select this keyframe
2. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
3. Select the destination frame (<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>)
4. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (paste)

Or in one step:

1. Select keyframe (<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>)
2. Duplicate and move with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>